# MongoDB / Mongoose has many Relationship

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm trying to figure out population and relationships in Mongo/Mongoose. I've got a Fixture that will have many predictions. If I want to show the fixture of a prediction I can simply use the populate method, but what if I need to show all the predictions for a fixture?

This sounds simple enough but maybe I've still got my SQL head on trying to figure it out. Is this easy to do or am I approaching it in the wrong way? Here's my models -

```
var FixtureSchema = new Schema({
homeTeam: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    ref: 'Team'
},
awayTeam: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    ref: 'Team'
},
date: {
    type: Date
},
matchday: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
}
});

var PredictionSchema = new Schema({
goalsHomeTeam: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
goalsAwayTeam: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
fixture: {
    type: Number,
    ref: 'Fixture'
},
user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to first find the fixture you want, then search through your predictions and find the matches. Mongo does not have a 'reverse' population, but writing your own is easy:

```
Prediction.find({fixture: fixture._id}, function(err, predictions) {
    //do things with predictions
})
```

Comment: Thanks Grant. My problem is what if I want to retrieve an array of fixtures and populate all the predictions for all of them? Is that possible?

Comment: There isn't really a simple and fast way to do that. You can't "populate" because fixture doesn't store a reference to all of its predictions. You can populate arrays of _id's, but that would require you to update the fixture object each time you create a new prediction.

Another possible solution is the [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async). Specifically the "each" function. Loop through fixtures, and for each one, find all Predictions and return the array.

Comment: Ok great. I believe that's going to solve my problem. Thanks for your help Grant.